# Анализ полученных по intent данных android

Tags: android

У меня есть активити на которое я передаю данные с других активити при помощи intent. Вот например у меня есть две активити в каждой из которых есть по одному ключу для передачи значений переменных, назовем их "first"/"second", дальше мы их инициализируем в активити которая является финальной в нашем приложении. То есть мне нужно как-то различать с какой активити пришла переменная. Я если честно с трудом представляю как это реализовать. Я думаю что нужно как-то это все провернуть с switch->case, что-бы при проверке я присваивал значение входящей переменной переменной которая была объявлена на финальной активити. У нас есть например переменная value и мы смотрим: если пришел ключ first от value присваивается одно значение, а если пришел ключ second то присваивается другое значение. Возможно я путано объяснил свой вопрос, если что-то будет не очень понятно то спрашивайте. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

### UPDATE

Мой последний код для получения значения через intent,
класс-адаптер1, нажатие на элемент списка - это передача информации:

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()+ keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

класс-адаптер, нажатие на элемент списка - это передача информации:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter2.class.getSimpleName()+ keyOutboundMessageId,message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

класс-приемник:

```
private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id"; // для входящих
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id"; // для исходящих
    private static Integer type,id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_show);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName())) {
                id = intent.getExtras().getInt(keyIncomingMessageId, 0);
                type = 0;
            }
            else if (extras.containsKey(MessageAdapter2.class.getSimpleName())) {
                id = intent.getIntExtra(keyOutboundMessageId,0);
                type = 1;
            }
        }


        showMess(id, type);
    }

    private void showMess(Integer key, int type) {
```

почему-то так и не заработал, не могу понять почему, все равно ошибка выводится:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
08-09 09:03:25.384 21114-21114/com.example.developer_4.test_login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 21114
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.MessageShow}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.MessageShow.onCreate(MessageShow.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

ошибка указывает что проблемной является строка в классе-приемнике, в методе `onCreate->showMess(id, type);`

Comment: да я уже заметил свою ошибку, но это не решило мою проблему, приложение все-равно слетает.

Comment: да, не могу понять почему если честно, уже вроде все прописано а оно все равно ругается

Comment: все так-же, ошибка не изменилась, может докинуть в вопрос что-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяйте ключ так:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras()
if(extras.containsKey("keytocheck")) {
 //Do stuff because extra has been added
}
```

Comment: не помогло(( видать что-то не учел)) слетело приложение, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.MessageShow}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko потому что `getExtras` может вернуть null.

Comment: а как он может вернуть null если я ему передаю данные? все работает без условия, то есть если использовать только `getExtras`... теперь мне вообще ничего не понятно))

Comment: я пробовал поставить условие noNull но это все-равно не помогло(

Comment: обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Вы напутали с ключами и обращаетесь к несуществующим ключам, как для проверки наличия ключа, так и для извлечения данных. Ключ отправки и получения должен быть одинаков, в этом смысл отправки значений по ключу (отправляете данные с ключом `MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()+ keyOutboundMessageId`, а принять пытаетесь от несуществующих по отдельности ключей `MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()` и  `keyOutboundMessageId`

отправка:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()+ keyOutboundMessageId,message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

прием:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_show);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.containsKey(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()+ keyOutboundMessageId)) {
            id = intent.getIntExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName()+ keyOutboundMessageId, 0);
            type = 0;
        }

}
```

аналогично второй, только везде вместо `MessageAdapter` - `MassageAdapter2` и вместо `keyOutboundMessageId` - `keyIncomingMessageId`

Comment: спасибо) теперь заметил что напутал)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko думаю справедливо будет принять [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866485/177345), так как именно он ответил на ваш действительный вопрос первым (как узнать откуда пришел интент). То, что вы перепутали ключи - это же не проблема вашего вопроса.

Comment: да вы правы, я изменил свою оценку.

Answer (score 1):

Присваивайте ключу имя активити, например:

`intent.putExtra(Activity.class.getSimpleName() + "_key", "...")`

при получении:

```
    if (intent.getExtra() != nulll) {
        if (intent.getExtra().contains(Activity.class.getSimpleName()){
            String extra = intent.getStringExtra(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: обновил вопрос)

Comment: сама идея правильная, но код неверный - ключи отпрвляемого интента не соответствуют принимаемым (смотрите [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866599/177345))

Comment: я дал лишь направление